# Android-App: Picking an Audiofile with ACTION_PICK from SD Card and save it to the Apps folder

Tags: android, audio, sd-card

I got this working with Images like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                image = new File(projectPathFull,"testapp_"+imageCounter+".jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
```

This creates the picked image in my folder testapp
But it doesnt work with Audiofiles somehow.
This is my code:

```
Intent toAudioSelect = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                audio = new File(projectPathFull,"testapp_"+imageCounter+".mp3");
                toAudioSelect.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(audio));
                startActivityForResult(toAudioSelect, REQUEST_PICK_AUDIO);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: still you are searching for answer?